# What is this pop up called?

Tags: ios, popup

Just a simple question.
I was asking about the window that comes out when for instance we want to save an image from the Facebook app on iOS to our iPhone. I just wanted to know what is this window called. And is it a ready made class in Xcode like for instance the `UIAlertController` or its just a `UITableView` just customised?
Thanks in advance.

[image: My question was on the image]

Comment: It's an ActionSheet. You can get this element using a UIAlertController and setting the preferredStyle property.

Comment: Before posting a question like this, please view the [UI Elements](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Bars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH12-SW1) section of the [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556).

Comment: Thanks rmaddy ... I never knew about these guidelines it helped me a lot. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is called an [Action Sheet](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIActionSheet) and can be created via [`UIAlertController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIActionSheet) starting from iOS 8.0